# Need Sql Server Hosting 50GB or More

Tags: dedicated-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am looking for a Hosting solution (Dedicated or Shared) which will allow me to host a SQL Server database service (Not SQL Express but the Web edition). The size of my database might grow to 50GB or more. The web application will offer more reads than write operations. I also need daily backups and raid 1 storage. Is there a reliable and economical hosting company that would provide this?

Additional Question: If there is a easy way to host MS SQL on Amazon EC2 service, it will be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I have several sites hosted on [Arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/asp_net_web_hosting), one of those has a MS SQL database nearly 2GB in size and I pay only the "unlimited" fee of $8 a month. The hosting has been pretty stable (certainly worth $8 a month).  The admin frontend they have could use some work, it does allow for restoral and backups from and to files you can FTP to the site, but overall I would recommend them.

Comment: That's what I have right now too :) I think 4-8gb will be enough for my uses. If the time comes, I might have to get a dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget Windows Azure SQL Database is out on the market with up-to <strike>50gb</strike> 150gb per-partition.

- [SQL Database on MSDN](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/sql-database/)
- [Comparing SQL Server to SQL Azure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/comparing-sql-server-with-sql-azure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Rackspace cloud. I use it and it works. You get dedicated virtual servers with root access and the pricing options, at least for me, were much more affordable than Amazon.

Comment: I was researching on Rackspace as well. I read on the forums that they bill way too much for technical support. What does your experience say?

Comment: Actually, Rackspace doesn't go as high as 50GB for cloud products. They only go as high as (approx) 16GB - http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing/

Comment: I believe that is 16GB memory per server, not storage space. That comes with 620GB storage. Also, you can always start up multiple server and cluster them, set up a smaller server to handle load balancing, etc.. You're only limited by your imagination and your budget

Answer (score 0):

You should look at some dedicated servers at www.softlayer.com - Top of the top
and might be some others, cheapier like WebHostingWorld etc.

There is a huge and extensive list of ads and reviews at WebHostingTalk